# Can't use SpeechKit Titanium module from iOS in my app

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

I want want to use Speechkit SDK in my app, since I found it recognize words better than the native tool did.
I found a Titanium module [on GitHub](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.SpeechKit) but it is designed to work with Titanium SDK 3.1.3.GA . I am currently working with SDK 5.0.0.GA.

What am I supposed to do to import this module in my mobile app ? I updated the titanium.xcconfig file to reflect the version of my SDK. I also put my credentials into it and build the project. Then I compressed it and installed it via Help Menu > Install Mobile Module. I finally added it to the tiapp.xml file.

When I try to run the project, this is what I get :

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld Build/Intermediates/Hello5.build/Debug-iphoneos/Hello5.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Hello5 normal arm64
[ERROR] :   Ld Build/Intermediates/Hello5.build/Debug-iphoneos/Hello5.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Hello5 normal armv7
[ERROR] :  (2 failures)
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/feeder/.appcelerator/install/5.0.1/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:89:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
```

I tried to create a new module by hand and drag-and-drop files into it, and also tried to install globally vs project-specific, I can't come with an idea for making it work. Thank you in advance if you could share an idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and looking the console using Trace appears "framework SpeechKit not found".

I've successfully resolved this error by packaging the module to your project directly selecting "Mobile App Project" given that Module.xcconfig sets "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" to find SpeechKit framework on "assets" folder from the project directly.

Comment: I slightly modified it suggesting it is an answer and not a "Me too" question or comment. Please advise if it is not an answer.

Comment: That's the answer. I just wanted to add first a brief introduction to say that it happened to me too, nothing else.